# Django Making 1000 Duplicate Queries

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, mptt

Model:

```
class Comment(MPTTModel):

    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="post_comments")
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name="children")
    text = models.CharField("Text", max_length=1000)
    rank = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Iterating through nodes has the same effect (>1000 queries).

Comment: With the toolbar, can you show the traceback included? I think you can click the side of the sql or something

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue with MPTT models. It was solved with `select_related`
(also for parent's foreign keys).
So, depending on your needs, proper queryset can looks like:

```
Comment.objects.select_related('post', 'submitter', 'parent', 'parent__submitter', 'parent__post')
```

Also, if you need comment's children in your loop as well, it can be optimized like that:

```
queryset.prefetch_related('children')
```

Or even like that:

```
queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'children', 
        queryset=Comment.objects.select_related('post', 'etc.'),
        to_attr='children_with_posts'
    )
)
```

... and depending on tree depth, you can use that:

```
queryset.select_related('parent', 'parent__parent', 'parent__parent__parent') 
# you got the idea:)
```

Answer (score 4):

Duplicated queries happens because all objects from iteration hits the data base when you refer a related object.

Try using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in your view method.

Probably using django prefetch related or select related will resolve that, but if not work, sorry you will need a raw query.

Have you ever read about optimizing Django queries? Here is a simple tutorial that's explain a lot of things: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/optimization/